# UIButton Subclass using its size to set corner radius with Autolayout

Tags: swift, uibutton, autolayout, subclass

I have the following subclass of `UIButton` just to give a circular border to a `UIButton`, assuming height and width of `UIButton` are set equal. But when auto layout does its job I do not get the correct radius. How can I change this class to behave correctly with auto layout?

```
import UIKit

class CircularButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.height / 2
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: can you pls put screenshot?

Comment: The problem is when init is running, the view of CircularButton does not have its final self.bounds.size set correctly yet. Because of what Autolayout will do later (after init). Therefore the corner radius gets a value that is not necessarily half of final value of  self.bounds.size.height / 2. I think this is clear and a screen shot does not reveal any secret.

Answer (score 0):

*Always* call:

```
setNeedsLayout()
layoutIfNeeded()
```

before accessing a view's frame or bounds when using AutoLayout. Otherwise, your accessing the view's size before its been set by AutoLayout. Calling these two methods forces an AutoLayout pass, allowing you to access the view's correct size.

Also, you should set the corner radius in `awakeFromNib` instead of `init`.

Comment: Your suggestion did not work but this worked:     override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.height/2
    }